# Не показываются приложения в меню gnome (ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Хотел отсортировать иконки в меню приложений по туториалу с сайта: http://softhelp.org.ua/?p=7223

Но в итоге иконки приложений просто перестали отображаться

Все .desktop файлы на месте, через поиск тоже всё находится.

Как это исправить?

EDIT: помог сброс настроек gnome командой dconf reset -f /org/gnome/

[image: Вот что происходит, если зайти в меню приложений]

Comment: что пишут логи?

Comment: Nov 22 18:00:08 ubuntu20 gnome-shell[8847]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._pages[pageIndex] is undefined#012getItemsAtPage@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/iconGrid.js:895:17#012_getChildrenToAnimate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/iconGrid.js:1307:40#012animateSpring@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/iconGrid.js:1582:27#012_onShowAppsButtonToggled/overviewShownId</<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:1930:38

Comment: ничего не понятно. на всякий случай отключите все расширения Gnome-Shell и временно поставте дефолтную тему adwaita или какая там тема на убунте?! Это чтобы исключить лишние записи в логах, которые у вас постоянно пишутся.

Comment: После отключения перезагрузите компьютер, чтобы отделить старые логи от актуальных. И потом загрузите на pastebin (а лучше сюда, в вопрос, под спойлер)полный лог с момента загрузки GDM или что там на убунте вместо GDM?!

Comment: @DiD сделал как сказали, когда открываю меню появляется такое сообщение: https://pastebin.com/2sg7sdUQ

Comment: тогда попробуйте сбросить все настройки командой `gsettings reset` от обычного пользователя неROOT

Comment: @DiD Помогло, спасибо! Правда пришлось использовать чуть-чуть другую команду, но это, думаю, не так важно (dconf reset -f /org/gnome/)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116538/discussion-between-did-and-trifonov-dmitriy).